# I got notification on two new answers, I can't see them

Tags: support, bug

I saw a notification in the inbox, informing me about 2 new answers on my [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/31296/adding-third-channel-to-the-pic32-starter-kit-dma-chaining-and-pwm-example/). I went to check them, but I can't see them.

The quote about the answer is "I experimented with looking at your web site in my cellphone and the format doesnt seem to be cor...", which might not be even related to my question. Possibly the notification was just a glitch in the software?

I could not find "tech support" for the site itself anywhere, so I'm posting this here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a spam poster trying to get his link on as many questions as possible. It was not a real answer of any sort, they were deleted and you are not yet high enough rep to see deleted content.

Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: It would help, and decrease the amount of confusion to have maybe something like a gray _** Something has been deleted **_ text.

Comment: @varesa, this is a special case where you were notified as the poster, for everyone else they get to enjoy not having screen space taken up due to one person spamming. If you are notified and you see something like this in the future we can also answer you in the [ask a mod channel](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/895/ee-ask-a-moderator). We will ping you back as soon as we are on and can clear these things up.